# XCode: How to add search include path in empty project

Tags: xcode, xcode5.1

I develops PHP extension, and have a problem with search include paths.

With development i create a empty project (Create new project -> Other -> Empty), and add header file:

```
#include "php.h"
```

And if i CMD+Click on this file, XCode view `Symbol not found`. In project configuration section `Search paths` not exists ;(

In project build setting i have only `User Defined` section.

How i add include paths to XCode, if i created empty project?

Thank.

**P.S.**

XCode - 5.1.1

Comment: Just add the relevant files to the project and then you won't need to explicitly specify any paths.

Comment: I try... And still error (Symbol not found)...

Answer (score 0):

As solution:

Add target Command line application, then there will be search paths section.